# Convert a formatted file size to bytes

Tags: java, converting, file

I needed to convert a formatted file size back into its length in bytes. I came up with the following code but want it reviewed:

```
/**
 * Converts a formatted size to its equivalent in bytes.
 * 
 * @param size
 *            The formatted file size. Examples: "125.5 MB", "1KiB", "0.8 GB"
 * @return
 * @throws NumberFormatException
 */
public static long getBytesFromFormattedSize(final String size) throws NumberFormatException {
    final String[] arr = size.toUpperCase().split(" ");
    if (arr.length != 2) {
        if (arr.length == 1 && Character.isDigit(size.charAt(0))) {
            // Treat this as a formatted size missing the space.
            return getBytesFromSize(size);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected '<size> <unit>', got '" + size + "'");
    }
    final char unit = arr[1].charAt(0);
    if (unit == 'B') {
        return Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
    }
    final int bytes = arr[1].length() == 3 && arr[1].charAt(1) == 'I' ? 1000 : 1024;
    final char[] units = {
            'K', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E'
    };
    int exp = 1;
    for (final char ch : units) {
        if (unit == ch) {
            break;
        }
        exp++;
    }
    return (long) (Double.parseDouble(arr[0]) * Math.pow(bytes, exp));
}

private static long getBytesFromSize(final String size) {
    String fixedSize = "";
    for (final char c : size.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c) && !fixedSize.contains(" ")) {
            fixedSize += ' ';
        }
        fixedSize += c;
    }
    return getBytesFromFormattedSize(fixedSize);
}
```

Some tests:

```
String[] sizes = {
        "1 KB", "100 MB", "100MiB", "1 GB", "100B", "1.5 MB"
};
for (String size : sizes) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s = %d bytes", size, getBytesFromFormattedSize(size)));
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 1 KB = 1024 bytes
> 100 MB = 104857600 bytes
> 100MiB = 100000000 bytes
> 1 GB = 1073741824 bytes
> 100B = 100 bytes
> 1.5 MB = 1572864 bytes
> ```

Comment: Do you wish to consider 1KB vs 1Kb?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, hope you get some great answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The function throws `NumberFormatException` and `IllegalArgumentException`.
2. Your implementation caters to your edge cases, take these for example:

   - 1Kb (Do you wish to handle bits). This gets converted to 1KB (unwantedly).
   - 1M iB (Incorrect position of space)
   - 1 (No units).

   Not sure if the input is manual or system feeded.
   Why not have a function that validates the input and if it can be tailored (1MiB), it returns a operable string.
3. A Map can be used instead of the units' char array, for loop and `Math.pow` for each input.
4. `getBytesFromFormattedSize()` calls `getBytesFromSize()` which again calls `getBytesFromFormattedSize()`. Instead a flow as this would look clean.

   ```
    getBytesFromFormattedSize(){
        //Get a valid string (if possible) (in two forms value and unit)
        // Proceed thereof.
    }
   ```
5. `fixedSize.contains()`  has an O(n) time complexity. Instead a boolean would easily suffice the otherwise redundant call once we insert a space.
6. Names such as `arr`, `size`, `bytes` are ignorant to their puprose.
7. Too much of hard coded values to actually understand the flow.
8. Should `I` return 1000? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte
9. `return Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);` assumes that the value would not be greater than INT_MAX? Does the input guarantee that?
10. If `size` is an empty string, charAt(0) could give exception `IndexOutOfBoundsException()`.

Comment: Some good stuff to consider, thanks. I'll wait a bit for any other answers and then mark one as accepted later.